# How to POST JSON attributes with underscore?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, axios

**The issue:**
On the server, I'm receiving my `api_key` parameter as `api key` (**with space instead of underscore**), how do I send it *with* underscore?

**Code:**

```
data = {
  api_key: this.state.api_key
}

axios.post('/resource', data)
  .then(response => { console.log(response) });
```

I'm using both **React** and **axios** (*must* use axios) on the frontend, and **Rails** on the backend.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The rails action which first receives the parameters:

```
private

resource_params
  ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params)
end
```

Comment: a bit confused on what you're trying to do, are you asking how to make rails send the param with underscore? or would you like JS to also send the param without underscore

Comment: This question is unrelated to [tag:json] or [tag:react].

Comment: How are you seeing or checking that Rails is receiving the key with a space and not underscore?

Comment: through the server output

Comment: Can you provide any additional details on that?  I'm almost certain this is a Rails issue.  What method are you using to receive the request?

Comment: For example, I have this api_key as well as an api_password field; Once POSTed, the server logs the received params as "api key", "api password", and then the server errors out stating that "password" is an undefined method, though I have no single fields called password, hence why I believe that the issue is this spacing that is going on when I receive the params.

Comment: Got it, can you please post your controller or the relevant controller action in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162620/discussion-between-xavier-and-filipe-gorges-reuwsaat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours beating my head about this, I've found the culprit: **Visual Studio Code**

This is the output on **VS Code**:

[image: vscode]

And this is the output on **linux terminal**:

[image: terminal]

This is such a stupid issue but it never occurred to me that the bloody text editor would omit the underscores.

Trully **@chris-g**, this wasn't an issue with JSON or React, it was on the Rails side as **@Xavier** suspected, though the issue is unrelated to the lack of underscores themselves.

This is what I get for giving Microsoft some credit after so long.

Answer (score 1):

Axios [serializes object params with `JSON.stringify`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L51), which means the request is almost certainly being sent how you want (unless you are transforming it somehow).  The issue is probably something on the Rails end.  Looking at your `resource_params` method, I can see you are using ActiveModelSerializers's JSON API adapter.  However, the request you are sending with Axios is not [JSON API Compliant](http://jsonapi.org/).  You might try `JSON.parse(params)` instead or better yet, use [Strong Params](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).  Also you mentioned that you are using `resource_params` as a before action, but it doesn't look like you are assigning an instance variable there as one might expect. How are you handling that response?  Are you calling that method directly in your action as well?

Anyway if that doesn't help I would be happy to continue our discussion in the chat.

Comment: It was my mistake to point as a before_action, it wasn't, just a function called as parameters to methods receiving params; I've omitted the JSON API standards/rest of the attributes for brevity given how many there were. In the end, the issue was Visual Studio Code's console as you can see in my answer, but thanks a lot for the quick replies and for your time :)